# Computer Fan - Can I use a fan with a different wattage than the original?

Tags: nas, fan, cooling

A fan recently died on a Synology NAS that we are using.

The fan is an 80mm Sunon MagLev KDE1208PTV3 DC12V 0,8W 79,5 x 80 x 29,5

However, looking on eBay Germany it's hard to find this exact fan, especially with the three pins required for the fanspeed to be reported to the NAS.

There is another fan that comes up, and is rated as something 'equivalent' according to the seller – the auction title is: ME80251V1-A99 Axial-Lüfter 80x80x25mm 12V 1,7 W= 69,6m³/h von Sunon = KDE1208PTV1-13A

The sizes differ slightly, but since the newer fan is narrower, it should fit fine in the case.

**My question thus is**, does this discrepancy in wattage/amperage matter? The amperage is about double (145ma vs 70ma), but the CFM is also about double (70m³/h vs 30m³/h) so heat shouldn't be an issue, in fact improved (noise isn't a concern as it's in a separate server room).

Comment: The prudent action would be to not draw more current than the old fan.  You don't know how much over-capacity the power-supply has, so there is no way to determine what is "safe".  Granted it's "only" a watt, but how thorough has your search been?  Besides eBay, have you looked at real electronic component sellers/distributors?

Comment: It is not only "only" a watt, it is a difference of just 0.075 amps. Less than a tenth of an amp! If the power supply can't handle an extra tenth of an amp on the 12 volt line, something is horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine. A standard 3-pin fan header won't have any problems supplying 145 ma. The new fan, being thinner, may not deliver the same pressure as the old, but since it is supposed to be able to move twice the air (in a no-resistance situation), it should be fine there too.

It will be considerably louder, but as you say, if it's off in a server room that's not an issue.